# integration google calendar with fullcalendar

Tags: json, symfony, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

i am working on a project symfony3 to integrate googleCalendar with fullcaldendar. I'd like to use the googlecalendar to feed the fullcalendar to show all the events i had in googlecalendar,and then each time when i change a event in fullcalendar, it will be changed also in googlecalendar. So the step is to get the google events from googleCalendar which i have done already and i have tried to make it in format of json:

$myjsonfile:

```
[{
"title": "Rdv Ecole",
"start": "2017-11-13T10:00:00+01:00",
"end": "2017-11-13T12:00:00+01:00"
 }, {
"title": "testing functions",
"start": "2017-11-20T13:15:00+01:00",
"end": "2017-11-20T14:15:00+01:00"
 }, {
"title": "another test",
"start": "2017-11-20T17:30:00+01:00",
"end": "2017-11-20T18:30:00+01:00"
 }, {
"title": "reuinion data vc",
"start": "2017-11-21T09:00:00+01:00",
"end": "2017-11-21T10:00:00+01:00"
 }]
```

Because i am using symfony3, so i make a

```
 return $this->render('calendar/loadcalendar.html.twig',['gevents'=>$myjsonfile]);
```

And then in my page to show the event:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function(start, end) {
                var title = prompt('Event Title:');
                var eventData;
                if (title) {
                    eventData = {
                        title: title,
                        start: start,
                        end: end
                    };
                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', eventData, true); // stick? = true
                }
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('unselect');
            },

            eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
            eventSources: [
                {
                    url: "http://localhost/prog/web/app_dev.php/calendar/load",
                    dataType: "json",
                    method: 'GET'
                }
            ],
            eventClick: function(event) {

                var title = prompt('Change Event title:');
                event.title = title;
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('updateEvent', event);

            }
        });
```

Now the problem is that i can't load the events from the json i have send,so can someone give me some advices? thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "can't"? Does your event source URL not work? What happens when fullCalendar tries to call it? Any errors in the console, or network tabs in the browser? Any server errors?

Comment: this is no error, it shows it catch a request ajax by this url: http://localhost/prog/web/app_dev.php/calendar/load?start=2017-11-20T00%3A00%3A00&end=2017-11-27T00%3A00%3A00&_=1511176051885

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project, I do it this way:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    /* [...] */
    events: "{{ path('ajax_calendar_load') }}",
    /* [...] */
```

And my load action return regular json:

```
    $response = new JsonResponse();
    $response->setContent($events);
    return $response;
```