# integration google calendar with fullcalendar (v2.0)

Tags: javascript, json, fullcalendar, google-calendar-api

Hello I want to ask a question about my [ancient one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47390422/integration-google-calendar-with-fullcalendar) because i want to post the code i have and i don't think i can do it in the comment of my ancient question, so i open a new question.

All i want is to make fullcalendar and googlecalendar function just as one calendar.

The problem is if i use the json format i used in my ancient question, fullcaldendar works perfect but if i want to add a attribute owner in my json to show who these events are belong to. Just like the new json i wrote under.And this time fullcalendar can't recognize the events, I want to ask is there a way to parse the json in fullcalendar so that it can read all format of json.

```
{
"owner": "*******@gmail.com",
"events": [{
    "id": "00cugf3q08rrdcqb51hesrmsjr",
    "title": "Rdv Ecole T\u00e9l\u00e9com avec Audrey D'ANGELO",
    "start": "2017-11-13T10:00:00+01:00",
    "end": "2017-11-13T12:00:00+01:00"
}, {
    "id": "23l1s9db4363hrn2btqhjpm4d7",
    "title": "testing functions",
    "start": "2017-11-20T13:15:00+01:00",
    "end": "2017-11-20T14:15:00+01:00"
}, {
    "id": "2u9t6p4ra6qoj5kdoru7dt18vj",
    "title": "another test",
    "start": "2017-11-20T17:30:00+01:00",
    "end": "2017-11-20T19:00:00+01:00"
}, {
    "id": "5d6rdt2ai7s1116h68912706cf",
    "title": "reuinion data vc",
    "start": "2017-11-21T09:00:00+01:00",
    "end": "2017-11-21T10:00:00+01:00"
}]
```

}

Comment: Not exactly like that. What you supply to to fullCalendar via `events:` **must** be an array containing event objects. But that's not to say you can't download some JSON like you've shown, process it and just give fullCalendar the "events" part, and use the rest of it for some other purpose. See https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event_data/events_function/ for how you could approach this.

Comment: Ok, i have seen the lien you gave, now i am able to solve my problem, thanks!